# How to fix "Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections" while connecting to oracle database from spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, hikaricp

I was trying to connect to my table and insert some data.We are using oracle database.
In the code I have used oracle thin driver ojdbc14.I am getting

```
2018-12-27 11:08:58.810  INFO 16548 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getNetworkTimeout()I)
2018-12-27 11:08:58.810 ERROR 16548 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z).
```

I am fairly new to spring boot and was actually trying to

do 
this demo -
https://www.devglan.com/spring-jdbc/working-with-springboot-jdbctemplate

only changes I have done is in my pom.xml and application.properties.

Is there any thing else needed for oracle? How i should solve this?All the example I see for oracle in net is with hibernate.Is is necessary to include hibernate approach?
Thank you in advance.

---

### pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HikariCP connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

---

### application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//url/service
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: ojdbc14.jar is very old. Try switching to ojdbc8.jar from 18.3 (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/jdbc-ucp-183-5013470.html) that requires JDK8. Also, the connection URL should be as shown. jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521/myorcldbservicename

Answer (score 8):

That is because you are using a very old version of ojdbc.
You should be using the latest versions of the Oracle JDBC driver to connect to your Oracle database.

From a quick test here:

- the warning is still present with version 11.2.0.1
- there is no warning with version 12.1.0.2
- oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getNetworkTimeout API is in Oracle JDBC 12.1.0.2(https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/toc.htm).
- but oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getNetworkTimeout API is not in Oracle JDBC 11.2.0.1(https://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnectionWrapper.html)

Comment: For those who will face with the sane issue, but working with postgresql: the solution is the same, just update a driver dependency.
I was getting the error. Then updated from `org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1` to `org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.1` and it's working fine